# How to prevent Html.RenderAction method to be recognized as html code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add an Render.Action to Html using javascript on an onChange event on a dropdown.
However when writing the @{Html.RenderAction} in javascript, it is viewed as html code instead of javascript code, and also executes before the script has triggered.

I want the  @{Html.RenderAction} in javascript to be javascript code only, and then when added to the Html, work as intended.

Any ideas?

html:

```
<select id="Categories-Dropdown">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">- Select Category -</option>
    <option value="2">Option 1</option>
    <option value="3">Option 2</option>
    <option value="4">Option 3</option>
    <option value="5">Option 4</option>

</select>
```

javascript:

```
function changed() {
        var ID = document.createElement("div");
        ID.innerHTML = '@{Html.RenderAction("RenderCategories", "ScannableNotes");}' // This is the problem
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to execute the render action until the javascript function executes and not when the function is defined?

Comment: Yes, right now the render action in the javascript executes before the function is triggered, which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do to achieve this,

First instead of rendering in JS I would put it in html inside an invisible div:

```
<div class="js-scannable-notes" style="display: none;">
    @Html.Action("RenderCategories", "ScannableNotes")
</div>
```

and then just read the content of that div from JS:

```
function changed() {
    var html = document.querySelector('.js-scannable-notes').innerHTML;
    // use your html here as you see fit
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to javascript. What should I do with the variable "html"?

Comment: @Royal since you want to render that piece of html after the javascript function is called then the approach given above won't work. You have to make an ajax call to the server from the `changed` js function and it will then return the piece of html you need.